# how to alias signals from a nested interface in system verilog?

Tags: system-verilog, assertions, assertion, system-verilog-assertions

I have a nested interface, something like the pseudo example

```
interface a();
 logic a;
endinterface: a

interface B();
  logic b;
  a A();
  alias b = A.a; // THIS throws an error
endinterface: b
```

I want to write assertions on `interface a` from `interface B`

But it does not allow me to `alias` the signal. What are other alternatives?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would just use A.a for the assertions. If you don't like this syntax, you can assign it to b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables and hierarchical references cannot be used in `alias` statements.

Your alternatives are:

- Use `assign b = A.a;` instead of `alias`
- Just use `A.a` in your assertion
- Declare `b` using the `let` construct `let b = A.a;`

I suggest using the `let` statement.

Comment: Hi Dave
for `assign` case we need to be aware of the direction in case we are using the 2nd interface for our TB.

Comment: Can you please tell me why you favor `let` over using `A.a`?

Comment: Yes, for the `assign` you do need to be aware of the direction. You said you were writing assertions, so that would not be a problem until you introduce more functionality.

Comment: I prefer avoiding hierarchical references as a general practice. The names get long and they make the code difficult to read and maintain.